# android "font has been blocked"

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

I want to use ttf font from web in android, but got error while loading.

Html of web page:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">@font-face {
    font-family: pfbulletinsanspro-light; /* Гарнитура шрифта */
    src: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/extrashop.images/demo/olymp/pfbulletinsanspro-light.ttf); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
   }
   div {
    font-family: pfbulletinsanspro-light;
   }
</style>
<div><span style="font-size:26px;">Тестовая страница<br />
Съешьте еще этих мягких французских булок</span></div>
```

Android code :

```
    webView = (WebView) res.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new LoadLinkWebViewClient());

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url, new HashMap<String, String>() {
            {
                put("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
            }
        });
```

I got error from chromium

> "Font from origin 'https://s3.amazonaws.com' has
>   been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin ' *base url of my site* ' is therefore not allowed
>   access.", source:
>   '*url of page*'

Comment: Please, [check this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to a font located on 3rd party domains, because of security reasons.
You should download the font and put it into the "assets" folder in your project and refer from there

```
src: url('../fonts/pfbulletinsanspro-light.ttf');
```

Or download an inject programmatically.